# Exception calling "Parse" for IP address - Why?

Tags: powershell

So i'm updating something. It had previously used whoami.akamai.net but that's being replaced by whoami.ds.akahelp.net (and/or the protocol specific whoami.ipv4.akahelp.net and whoami.ipv6.akahelp.net). So need to update. Anyway when I do this

```
$ips = (((Resolve-DnsName 'whoami.ds.akahelp.net' -QuickTimeout -Type txt).Strings) -replace 'ns','').Trim();
$ips = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ips)
```

It generates an error - Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "An invalid IP address was specified." - but the IP is valid. Then I noticed there is what seems to be an extra line before the IP so that would account for the exception but I can not get rid of the line. I expected the output to be just the IP address. Anyway, I can not parse the IP, and the extra line before the IP renders the output useless where it feeds some other code because its being detected as an invalid IP in the rest of the code also when its really seeing that extra line (I think). So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: that seems like a very very roundabout way to get the IPv4 address. are you _sure_ that the cmdlet doesn't return it as an object? if not, then you likely otta just use another cmdlet/dotnet-call that DOES give you the actual IP.

Comment: I use this because the IP its returning is the IP making the query which is the dns and not the public IP, and i'm checking that the correct dns is being used. If I wanted the public IP i'd get it from some place like http://ipv4.whatismyip.akamai.com which does return the public IP but not the query IP. The cmdlet does return an object. Someone posted an answer which does work but I do not see it now so probably removed it, but its     $ips = ((Resolve-DnsName 'whoami.ds.akahelp.net' -QuickTimeout -type txt).Text -split ' ')[1] - to whoever posted that, thank you.

Comment: ah! thank you for the explanation ... i was quite confused ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

The returned object is an array, you need to specify which item in the array you need.

```
PS C:\Users\jacob> $ips

81.134.99.118

PS C:\Users\jacob> $ips.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                           
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                       



PS C:\Users\jacob> $ips[1]
81.134.99.118

PS C:\Users\jacob> $ips[1].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                           
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

So with the code you have, to specify the item in the array you need, you could write it as follows:

```
$ips = (Resolve-DnsName 'whoami.ds.akahelp.net' -QuickTimeout -Type txt).Strings[1].Trim()
$ips = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ips)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it 
 
`$ips = (Resolve-DnsName 'whoami.ds.akahelp.net' -QuickTimeout -Type txt).Strings[1]
$ips = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ips)`